# Counting Collinear Points

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, geometry

Given two points \$(x_1, y_1)\$ and \$(x_2, y_2)\$ with integer coordinates, calculate the number of integer points (excluding the given points) that lie on the straight line segment joining these two points. Use any [maths formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301890/how-many-points-between-two-points) you like, such as

$$gcd(|x_2 - x_1|, |y_2 - y_1|) - 1$$

**Input**

Four integer coordinates of the two points: \$x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2\$.

**Output**

Number of integer points between the two given points.

## Test Cases

[image: lines]

| Integer Coordinates | In-between Points |
| --- | --- |
| (5,10),(10,5) | 4 |
| (-8,5),(0,5) | 7 |
| (-3,-3),(2,2) | 4 |

Comment: You should give some harder test cases, like slope of 3/2.

Comment: And include one that goes down and to the left. I thought I could golf one, but it failed on just that case.

Comment: Consider add some testcases that result is 0: `(0,0),(1,1)`, `(1,1),(8,24)`, some test cases that x0=x1: `(0,0),(0,5)`

Comment: Do we need to handle vertical / horizontal lines?

Comment: @noodleman yes, that's one of the test cases.

Comment: Please don't put your answer in the challenge - instead, you are encouraged to answer your own question _as an Answer_.  That way, you get to accumulate more votes, too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 17 bytes

```
f(A,B)=gcd(A-B)-1
```

Takes input as two two-element lists.

This uses the formula as stated in the question, but it seems like `gcd` is always positive even with negative numbers, so I don't need to take the absolute difference, but rather just regular difference.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y4nexswqiy)

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 3 bytes

```
εġ‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLOtcSh4oC5IiwiIiwiWy01LDVdXG5bMTAsLTVdIl0=)

Port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269088/100664).

```
ε   # Absolute difference - [|x1-x2|,|y1-y2|]
 ġ  # gcd of that list
  ‹ # decrement
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ạg/’
```

A dyadic Link that accepts a point as a pair on each side and yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroXp@o8aZv7//z/axEBHQdc49n@0kYGpjoKhZSwA)**

#### How?

Implements the provided greatest common divisor formula.

```
ạg/’ - Link: pair of integers [x1, x2]; pair of integers [y1, y2]
ạ    - absolute difference (vectorises) -> [|x1-y1|, |x2-y2|]
  /  - reduce by:
 g   -   greatest common divisor -> GCD(|x1-y1|, |x2-y2|)
   ’ - decrement -> GCD(|x1-y1|, |x2-y2|) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for stating the method. I'm interested to see the various maths formulas that arise from this challenge.

Comment: There's pretty much only variations of gcd.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
≈đG←
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FisfdXYcmej-qG3CkuKk5GKo6IKbGtGmOoYGsQrRhgY6prFc0boWQEohGsox1tE1BvKMdIxiIRoA)

Takes input as two pairs of numbers, e.g. `[-8,5] [0,5]`.

```
≈đG←
≈       Absolute difference (vectorized)
 đ      Unpair; get the two elements of a pair
  G     GCD
   ←    Decrement
```

---

> I wonder how an approach that defines the solution to be an integer point on the line, and using `-n` for the final result. (I haven't really tried to learn Nekomata yet and somehow doubt it would be shorter for this problem, but seems interesting) – [noodle man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/noodle-man)

The shortest I can get using this approach is 10 bytes:

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 10 bytes

```
≈:Ṁᵉ{~Z*}¦
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FhsfdXZYPdzZ8HBrZ3VdlFbtoWVLipOSi6GyC26aRZvqGBrEKkQbGuiYxnJF61oAKYVoKMdYR9cYyDPSMQLyDHTA6ox0DE1jIdoB)

```
≈:Ṁᵉ{~Z*}¦      Take [-8,5] [0,5] as an example
≈           Absolute difference (vectorized)
                [-8,5] [0,5] -> [8,0]
 :          Duplicate
                [8,0] -> [8,0] [8,0]
  Ṁ         Maximum
                [8,0] [8,0] -> [8,0] 8
   ᵉ{       Apply the following block and then push the original top of stack
     ~Z       Choose any integer in [1,n)
                [8,0] 8 -> [8,0] 1 or [8,0] 2 or ... or [8,0] 7
       *      Multiply
                [8,0] 1 -> [8,0]
                [8,0] 2 -> [16,0]
                ...
                [8,0] 7 -> [56,0]
        }   End the block (ᵉ pushes the original top of stack)
                [8,0] -> [8,0] 8
                [16,0] -> [16,0] 8
                ...
                [56,0] -> [56,0] 8
         ¦  Divide and check if the result is an integer
                [8,0] 8 -> [1,0]
                [16,0] 8 -> [2,0]
                ...
                [56,0] 8 -> [7,0]
```

`-n` counts the number of solutions, so the output is `7`.

Comment: I wonder how an approach that defines the solution to be an integer point on the line, and using `-n` for the final result. (I haven't really tried to learn Nekomata yet and somehow doubt it would be shorter for this problem, but seems interesting)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≧⁻Ｎθ≔∨⁻ηＮθηＩＬΦ↔η∧ι¬﹪×ιθη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3BCsIwDAbgu0@RYwYV3MnDTkMQBDdFfIFuK2ugtrNNff3a2cswtz98yT9q6UcnTUoXu0Tu42tQHt9Vs9tmnXMnlzYEmu2DZs3YkY1BwFZVAtbDovDmi0H9p35MwPrz7skynmRgvCo7s8YzGc6oHYIzkVVuFtDaCUlA73Krm6Jx@KSXCuuuPCrTpFTDEeoD1Gn/MV8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: No vectorised difference or gcd, so I have to do things the hard way.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the first co-ordinate.

```
≧⁻Ｎθ≔∨⁻ηＮθη
```

Subtract the second co-ordinate, but if it is horizontal then make it diagonal, which has the same number of intermediate points.

```
ＩＬΦ↔θ∧ι¬﹪×ιηθ
```

Generate a list of intermediate y-coordinates and see how many x-coordinates are integers.

Comment: Maybe failed for `0 0 0 5`

Comment: @tsh Thanks, I've spent 3 bytes on a fix.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 7 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
¯1+∨/⍤-
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=O7TeUPtRxwr9R71LdAE&f=MzRQMFVIA2JDAy4I89B6CwVTLiMFIzDbGIQB&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function which takes vectors on the left and right and returns an integer.
I believe this solution also works in any dimension, not just 2D. It takes the difference of the points, GCD all of the differences, and adds -1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 12 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-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)</sup>

```
-1;⍢⊃◿∘±°⊟⌵-
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAgLTE74o2i4oqD4pe_4oiYwrHCsOKKn-KMtS0KCmYgNV8xMCAxMF81CmYgwq84XzUgMF81CmYgwq8zX8KvMyAyXzIK)

```
-1;⍢⊃◿∘±°⊟⌵-
           -  # difference
          ⌵   # absolute value
        °⊟    # uncouple pair to stack
  ;⍢⊃◿∘±      # GCD
-1            # decrement
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 97 bytes

```
,(.+),(.+),
,$2¶$1,
%O`[^,]+
\d+
$*
-(1+),(1+)
$1$2
(1+),-?\1|[^1¶]

mO^`^.*
^(1(1*))\1*¶\1*$
$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYo7CgIxFEX7u443kM9L8EUCdpaWs4DJhAhaWGghlq4rC8jGYmaEw@EeuO/75/G69kldSmflrf4LTKFVEsY0lyXzapFuFmTglGynIZBQwJ7unOS7ZGl1BZ5zLtkbZCVKjNZJTKtDBPKh98hy2IhwJ468jyMPAocf) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
,(.+),(.+),
,$2¶$1,
```

Exchange the first y-coordinate with the second x-coordinate and split the coordinates onto separate lines.

```
%O`[^,]+
```

Ensure that if either coordinate is negative then the first one is.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
-(1+),(1+)
$1$2
```

If the co-ordinates have different signs then add their absolute values together.

```
(1+),-?\1|[^1¶]
```

Otherwise take the absolute difference.

```
mO^`^.*
```

Sort them descending in case the first difference is zero.

```
^(1(1*))\1*¶\1*$
$.2
```

Calculate the decremented GCD.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 62 bytes

```r
\(x,y)max((y=1:max(z<-abs(x-y)))[!z[1]%%y&!z[2]%%y|!all(z)])-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY37WI0KnQqNXMTKzQ0Km0NrUCMKhvdxKRijQrdSk1NzWjFqmjDWFXVSjUgwwjEqFFMzMnRqNKM1dQ1hJqSm6aRrGGiY2ipqZOsYWikY2yqqckFEjPVMTQAixnowIR0LYBMoBCSiLGOrjFIyEjHCCpkomMCEgBRKAKmIE0QSxcsgNAA)

Base R has no built in for GCD.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
(p,q,r,s)=>(g=r=>s?g(s,s=r%s):r*r)(r-p,s-=q)**.5-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCoJAFEX3fcVsghm5I/OsQSnGvkVMpRBH34t@fzJahcJZ3cPhPpt3Iy0/5ped4r1LfUh6xgKGmFDrIXCo5TZogQQ@irlwxkaznSE2LCbLcm8ptXGSOHb5GAfdaw9yX7wx18O/shU89s0JKwWKrXJrQaCtWEdUKM77ye8mkSoVOUUf)

Basically based on the formula in the question. Calculate

$$ \sqrt{\left(\text{gcd}(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)\right)^2}-1 $$

where \$\text{gcd}\$ is defined as

$$ \text{gcd}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x & y=0 \\
\text{gcd}(y,x \bmod y) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: The square root seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Neil it is replacement of absolute values.

Comment: I've figured it out now... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 9 chars

```
¯1+∨/∣⎕-⎕
```

test&how use:

```
      ¯1+∨/∣⎕-⎕
⎕:
      ¯8 5
⎕:
      0 5
7
~

      ¯1+∨/∣⎕-⎕
⎕:
      5 10
⎕:
      10 5
4
~
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 104 bytes

*-5 bytes, thanks to @ceilingcat*

```
g(a,b){return b?g(b,a%b):abs(a);}main(x,y,a,b){scanf("%d%d%d%d",&x,&y,&a,&b);printf("%u",g(x-a,y-b)-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEAB/JQQaNrALrY@D7cFv2Y02FDRI02KC@OuuL@Y4wwSKIahGYBT/mM/LOicjxwiC3IjvWTKwH55XnhIUrPjrcuA0gm1Ofyy6gq6iY3Tih9s8peWrV4sRCjFWEk/dZ6O6aw1tzabdm@6g@grjhWNWur8B)

Comment: I think meta consensus is that you can write a function instead of a whole program.