# Ellipse Lattice Point Counter

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, geometry

## Challenge

Determine how many integer lattice points there are in an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1$$

centered at the origin with width \$2a\$ and height \$2b\$ where integers \$a, b > 0\$
.

**Input**

The Semi-major \$a\$ and Semi-minor \$b\$ axes.

**Output**

Number of *interior* and *boundary* points.

## Example

Ellipse plot showing \$a=5\$ and \$b=3\$ with \$41\$ blue interior and \$4\$ red boundary points.

[image: ellipse]

**Input**

\$5\$,\$3\$

**Output**

\$41\$,\$4\$

## Test Cases

| a | b | Interior | Boundary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 41 | 4 |
| 5 | 15 | 221 | 12 |
| 8 | 5 | 119 | 4 |
| 8 | 1 | 15 | 4 |
| 9 | 15 | 417 | 4 |
| 15 | 15 | 697 | 12 |
| 20 | 20 | 1245 | 12 |

Comment: Is there a closed form?

Comment: I don't think there's a closed form, I got the idea from the Gauss Circle Problem which there's no formula to find the number of lattice points and involves some enumeration.

Comment: I think it's more interesting to have separate questions for interior points and boundary points, as boundary points is a Pythagorean triple like \$(bx)^2 + (ay)^2 = (ab)^2\$.

Comment: For the Gauss circle problem, the number of interior and boundary points can be computed with Jacobi's two square theorem and the factorization of the radius length.

Comment: Oh, I'll have to take a closer look and hopefully try to understand it. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Related https://projecteuler.net/problem=804 Endagorion has a method that works for any shape with overlapping x ranges in O(circumference) by stepping through x ranges for each y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
rNŒp²÷²§’ṠĠẈṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I7@ikgkObDm8/tOnQ8kcNMx/uXHBkwcNdHQ93Tvv/cOdiy4e7ew4tebhjsVHYo6Y1h7Y@3LnP@lHDHAVdO4VHDXOtD7cDBVS4Hu7ecrgdKB/5/78ppzGniSGnCZcpp6Epp5GRIaehEZcFJ5BnaAkUteA0BImbcFmCKUNzINMQrNTM0hyk1MiAE4gMjUyAgkYA)

A monadic link that takes a pair of integers and returns a pair of integers. Works perfectly for all of the examples, but there is a theoretical risk of floating point inaccuracy.

### Explanation

```
rN            | Range from a to -a and b to -b
  Œp          | Cartesian product
    ²         | Squared
     ÷²       | Divide by a ** 2, b ** 2
       §      | Sum inner lists
        ’     | Subtract 1
         Ṡ    | Signs
          Ġ   | Indices of like items in groups
           Ẉ  | Lengths
            Ṗ | Remove last (those outside the border)
```

### Alternative [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
rNŒp²Uḋ²_²P$ṠĠẈṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I7@ikgkObQh/u6D60Kf7QpgCVhzsXHFnwcFfHw53T/j/cudjy4e6eQ0se7lhsFPaoac2hrQ937rN@1DBHQddO4VHDXOvD7UABFa6Hu7ccbgfKR/7/b8ppzGliyGnCZcppaMppZGTIaWjEZcEJ5BlaAkUtOA1B4iZclmDK0BzINAQrNbM0Byk1MuAEIkMjE6CgEQA)

This version only uses integer arithmetic so should always be accurate even for large inputs (though like the other answer has \$O(m \times n)\$ complexity).

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks. The test cases were confusing me!

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
function(a,b,z=c(a,b)^-2%*%t(expand.grid(-a:a,-b:b)^2))c(sum(z<1),sum(z==1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclNCoAgEEDhfadoE8zEGGkEIXmVQC2jRRb9QHR5S1ffg3cEl/csD@729lo2D5oMvcpGcWCiKIsLpmfXfqzmYxmBaamJGflfgWjhvFd4e46UQimOGBy01GAW4W20o4SoSdQYPg)

May have issues due to numerical precision. Naive algorithm: loop over all lattice points in the \$2a \times 2b\$ grid centered around the origin, and count the points with the requisite relationship.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 85 bytes

```r
function(a,b,p=a^2*b^2,z=c(b,a)^2%*%t(expand.grid(-a:a,-b:b)^2))c(sum(z<p),sum(z==p))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclNCoMwEEDhfU/hRpiRidgpQhFzlcBMbIoLY/AHipdP1dX34C05FL0pctij38Y5gpBSsuK4Usd0WA9Kgo7Lqtzg80sSh/q7jAMY6YSMdnpORA/rPsHRJ6Q7rE2IOUBLL3xcPNvLN91wQ9xg/gM)

More precise.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```r
\(a,b,y=b/a*(a^2-(-a:a)^2)^.5)c(B<-sum(!y%%1)-1,sum(y%/%1+.5)-B)*2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGSNAVbhaWlJWm6FjedYjQSdZJ0Km2T9BO1NBLjjHQ1dBOtEjXjjDTj9Ew1kzWcbHSLS3M1FCtVVQ01dQ11QJxKVX1VQ22gtK6TppYR1CTLNA1THWNNBS4QbWgKZljowGhDTSBlCRIH0oamUIaRgY6RgSbEgAULIDQA)

Total points of boundary plus interior is (up to precision error) $$\sum_{-a\le x \le a} \# \left\{ y \in \mathbb Z : |y| \le (b/a) \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \right\}$$

$$ = \sum_{-a \le x \le a} \left( 2 \left\lfloor (b/a) \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \right\rfloor + 1 \right)$$

\$B\$ counts boundary points, subtracting over-counted cases \$|y| = a\$.

`y=b*(1-(-a:a/a)^2)^.5` actually fails the test cases due to precision errors.

[Floating point tricks in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269339/17360)

-2 bytes by rearranging some terms, credit Giuseppe.

Comment: You can save another 2 bytes by reversing the order of output and a little manipulation; [Attempt it online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGSNAVbhaWlJWm6FjedYjQSdZJ0Km2T9BO1NBLjjHQ1dBOtEjXjjDTj9Ew1kzWcbHSLS3M1FCtVVQ01dQ11QJxKVX1VQ22gtK6TppYR1CTLNA1THWNNBS4QbWgKZljowGhDTSBlCRIH0oamUIaRgY6RgSbEgAULIDQA)

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 88 bytes

```
=frequency(sort(sequence(2*A1+1,1,-A1)^2/A1^2+sequence(1,2*B1+1,-B1)^2/B1^2),{1-9^-9,1})
```

Put \$a\$ in cell `A1`, \$b\$ in cell `B1` and the formula in cell `C1`. The output is in cells `C1:C2` with residue in `C3`.

Generates integer \$x\$ and \$y\$ sequences for lattice points in a rectangle that bounds the ellipse and calculates the distance from origin at each point. Uses [frequency()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094286) to find points within and on the ellipse. The residue shows points within the bounding rectangle but outside the ellipse. Uses [sort()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) but as an array enabler only.

Earlier proof-of-concept version to confirm that this is easily solvable in a spreadsheet (**160 bytes** golfed, 279 ungolfed):

```
=let(a, A1, b, B1, r, 
  map(sequence(2 * a + 1, 1, -a), lambda(x, 
    map(sequence(1, 2 * b + 1, -b), lambda(y, let( 
      d, x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2, 
      ifs( 
        d = 1, 2, 
        d < 1, 1, 
        1, 0 
      ) 
    ))) 
  )), 
  { countif(r, 1), countif(r, 2) } 
)
```

Comment: -8 `=let(a,A1,b,B1,r,tocol(map(sequence(2*a+1,1,-a),lambda(x,map(sequence(1,2*b+1,-b),lambda(y,let(c,x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2,ifs(c=1,2,c<1,1))))))),sort(countif(r,{1,2})))`

Comment: @z.. thanks. This was just to confirm that a simple algorithm gets the correct result. The formula can be golfed quite a bit (as [your answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269276/119296) shows.)

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 84 bytes

Assuming \$a\$ is in A1 and \$b\$ is in B1.

```cpp
=SORT(COUNTIF(SEQUENCE(2*A1+1,1,-A1)^2/A1^2+SEQUENCE(1,2*B1+1,-B1)^2/B1^2,{"<1",1}))
```

92 bytes

=SORT(COUNTIF(MAKEARRAY(2*A1+1,2*B1+1,LAMBDA(x,y,SUMSQ((x-A1-1)/A1,(y-B1-1)/B1))),{"<1",1}))




93 bytes

=LET(a,A1,b,B1,SORT(COUNTIF(SEQUENCE(2*a+1,1,-a)^2/a^2+SEQUENCE(1,2*b+1,-b)^2/b^2,{"<1",1})))

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 64 bytes

```
f(a,b)=[1+vecsum(v=2*Vec(qfrep([a,0;0,b]^2,a^2*b^2)))-t=v[#v],t]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY_BCoJAFEV_5WGbGXuCMyEUYfQVbR5jjKIhWEw2DvYtbdxE39Tf5Giu7uXcy3vc18fotj5fzDC8O1tF2--xYhpznpJYu7J4dFfmUhmeyoLdq7Y0jDTG-xhzlUnUmQzzTHLOI5s6WjmFVv3vNNqY5sl6iA5g2vpmWU9CQYAQQE9ydD4JoJo4ToxzBKIEYTMCryLxZouwqG_SbgnEXFF8_rls-AE)

Yes, PARI/GP has a built-in for this.

> `qfrep(q,B,{flag=0})`: vector of (half) the number of vectors of norms from `1` to `B` for the integral and definite quadratic form `q`. If flag is `1`, count vectors of even norm from `1` to `2B`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ýí€ûnR**`âOIPns-.±{Åγ¦
```

Outputs the pair in reversed order, so \$[boundaryCount, interiorCount]\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//8Odw63igqzDu25SKipgw6JPSVBucy0uwrF7w4XOs8Km//9bNSwzXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCf8Pzz289lHTmsO784K0tBIOL/KvDMgr1tU7tLH6cOu5zYeW/df5Hx1tqmMcqwMkDU2BlIUOhDQEkpYQIUOolJGBjpFBbCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý                # Convert both values in the (implicit) input-pair to [0,value]-ranged
                 # lists
 í               # Reverse each inner list
  €û             # Palindromize each inner list
    n            # Square each inner value
     R           # Reverse the list
      **         # Multiply each to the (implicit) input-pair twice
        `        # Pop and push both lists separately to the stack
         â       # Create all possible pairs using the cartesian product
          O      # Sum each inner pair together
           IP    # Push the product of the input-pair
             n   # Square that
              s- # Subtract the sums of the list from that value
.±               # Get the sign (-1 if negative; 0 if 0; 1 if positive) of each
  {              # Sort these -1s, 0s, and 1s
   Åγ            # Then run-length encode it, pushing list [-1,0,1] (which we won't use)
                 # and the list of lengths
     ¦           # Remove the first value (for the amount of -1s)
                 # (after which the resulting pair is output implicitly)
```

[Try it online with step-by-step debug lines.](https://tio.run/##bZK/bhNBEMZ7nmLkhiS6Q44QDRFKQYFSRIlCGUVi7RvfjbQ3e9k/tgIdEo9BQ0EFBUKiobN7HoIXMTO758SRKG/v@37ffDvrgpkRbreTMx5SfAmT6tX61@mTyWvHS/QRZi52EB0YuJ5WS2MT3tTecIsNWArZsPlcLFcojoCAZt4BMaN/kHwvkktjiRvvenr/X93fj982v4v07W0y/pEop6uKH@fFDmEw5MEtMiio5qpozpONNNi7wskEbaMW0sJ1NsYVzTP56Ghs79FEBGMtDC4EmtkSETRDzJJ6n/Ru82WcOPX746pe/1@M1VPocm7IxRoYvGvSPI7EvXHUdHbJO@gseiOyvQILuUDxUI4PdRG@wVjw1DIc1MdAC2BsTaQlnsBUP6cnkI@lEunxoWY/cJX2bP1jzHU@8/oKDDfgE9cWuZXHgDx3jcwbKxikE3Erj0NvQ2kZFOBg1ZFgVwiN46cRUpAw5ex0hZULfNh8@vNzt9HeLctCF3LZcdfX@Xxmepc42@vj@wySnSQvejYWPAZZ@KFi119Pt9vrF9Xzm38)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 110 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,q=2:[sum(0>(t:=x*x*b*b+y*y*a*a-a*a*b*b)or(q:=q+(t<1))*0for x in range(-a,a)for y in range(-b,b)),q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBDsIgEAXQvadgydBpAm2a1Ea8iLoYotUmlhbEpJwerRvRxSze//PnGG6TrdvZp16zY7rTaM7ECA06XXWHx3Pkcs9DpxexCCNMEUUUJKh832qYPHeddgUPOwUgZD95trDBMk/2euElIcGaxSwzaADQndLsBxt4zxusATZfqSZji79Smba/r@pvWkmsZN5/xukF)

Consider four quarter

Comment: Oops...my inefficient answer considered four quarters.

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYtBDoIwFET3nqIbkv9LSa1AgkS8iLr4DaIkUkipC7l8LboQXEwmb/JmeLl7b9JisL6p2Nk/qNM1MRK6PMFYVuOzg@0RXFnBJKVGzndccx3DFH2BOCUh84hkakY86y1zB9WEmlhrmCVzu0IwEFHKYCd6TqzEGAU7zi5@sK1x0EAuUsTNj1S@wEKsSS1ov1bV31V9ZP8G)?

Comment: @vengy 4x slower doesn't matter at all. Seems yours is shorter 4 quarter

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦＸ×η…·±θθ²ＦＸ×θ…·±ηη²⊞υ⁻Ｘ×θη²⁺ικＩ⟦ΣＥυ›ι⁰№υ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xC8IwEEb3/oqMF4igQifHDtKhpaibOMQSm2Cbtkmu/vx4EQRRXA4efO9xrZauHWUfY2knDDUOV@Vg5rvskzXxbXQMmvFBeDKD8qAFK23bozeLOkjbKahVJ4MiW7CZ09lyzn60@Z@mydBvrUGvAQWrjEX/7evXSLCGKmAEu3NODzbO2ACF9AHORxygklMq7J2iuku7NU/5YkTaYcILeTHm2SaPq6V/Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Similar approach to @vengy's C answer.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `a` and `b`.

```
ＦＸ×η…·±θθ²
```

Loop `x` from `-a` to `a` inclusive.

```
ＦＸ×θ…·±ηη²
```

Loop `y` from `-b` to `b` inclusive.

```
⊞υ⁻Ｘ×θη²⁺ικ
```

Calculate the squared distance in from the perimeter, multiplied by `a²b²`.

```
Ｉ⟦ΣＥυ›ι⁰№υ⁰
```

Output the number of points for where this is positive and the number for where this is zero.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language(Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>135</del> 106 bytes

Saved 29 bytes thanks to @vengy

---

Here `a` and `b` both are positive integers.

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7NT4NAEMXv/BVztGUaPkwTP7oX9EKipjcP69IMdJFN2l1TBi0h/O2INT0Zy2nmzXu/vNkTV3pPbAoahlLSBvONuhPPbtvstOxSEWIiwh4fnXw1XMmOxTGLA8pivx1nnsU9pqXkVYSp759WISJMfF8phd0RF4TUY9fiIse8V/ddikmvhgfXWH4iHov12hnLtSi9q/mL@8LWNVCQhabWwJWpoWxswcZZYAfFDzeeNex@Yfg40VC6A5Bt4c17N5/aAo1qC/l85v2tkkuEawVBsD6M8p9AtFQXAjcIU350yb@dKogmX4hDhDg8J4Zv)

```mathematica
f[a_,b_]:=Module[{I=0,B=0},Do[With[{t=x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2},If[t<1,I++,If[t==1,B++]]],{x,-a,a},{y,-b,b}];{I,B}]
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJNb4JAEL3zK97JtLINQmNiPzj1ZNI2Nj3StVlgURLZbWBpIYbfTkdRG02VZJOZN/PezOzsZsIsZSZMGom2fdKlMs/CEJIznSpTBOJzqoxcyJwh3Lsc9z5edFyuZGABayLKPNV5J4GPEZGpVCzy@i/WMOLSeS@zjQqYJsGu4FtQcQwGOMCaM2w5W1Y19xwx92CjJi8k7xEuw3Fb2z5Izoh8f6M6Hsy2@U7UWc62Zl0x3AgG0TCsa/JDEjaU4g/dJU7ufFq2sXh7NXzVP6zWJSKhUBYSZpkWSEoVmVQrGI1os28KS6y6peOrW1eicwhV48NapN9SQRCKEQ6vrX@eaMxwy@E4s5zgGYI75hcIE4a@vHspf9fXwO0dwaM/4432jPYX)

```mathematica
CountLatticePoints[a_Integer, b_Integer] := Module[
  {interiorPoints = 0, boundaryPoints = 0},
  
  Sum[
    If[IntegerQ[x] && IntegerQ[y], 
      If[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 < 1, interiorPoints++, 
        If[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1, boundaryPoints++]
      ]
    ],
    {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}
  ];
  
  {interiorPoints, boundaryPoints}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 87 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{*r=0,0,w=a*b;(k=*-w..w).product(k).map{|x,y|r[w*w<=>x*x+y*y]+=1[x%a+y%b]};r[0,2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCoMwEADQvV/RRdDLGaJFKNjzR8INSYuLlIagJEH99ijY7Q3PLzblkXI9GLQreFKoMJAB25cTQR2kDJV0/vdZ3nM5VfJr3LpFTJvXAcKLhghRJEgsqNGxMCIVlvfea4Ut79ndR93hg28Xmu7SE/9oz6Y4Hw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 96 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:divmod(sum((4j,4,0)[cmp(a*b,abs(x/a*a+x%a*b*1j))]for x in range(a*b+1))-2*a-2*b+1,1j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LDoIwEEX3fEU3Jp0yKkVIFMOXqIupgEJ4NAUNfj226gJZTHLP5Mxc/RruXRtORXqeampURoxQJVn5bLqM94@G86jCCAM4XRvNSSgk1fNxS4L8cWVZyArgUnSGjaxsmaH2ljvPlwDrUJAdm9FaU5YXTGtTtgPXkNieVB8/yNyKNianGtBl9c2e99MLHuMOYI4ynvMeFyjneFjYcnkeBhgGf4Z7ML0B)

Returns boundary,interior. Test bed borrowed from @l4m2 and modified. Testing code prettifies integer valued complex numbers into actual integers.

### How?

Uses complex numbers for two purposes:

1. abs with complex argument for Euclidean norm
2. as a means of 2d vector summation without importing any libraries.
   Special Python 2 semantics of div and mod for complex operands is used to recover real and imaginary parts after summing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
hMlBPx1Sm.acVdQ*Fm}_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8M3xymgwjA4Vy8xOSwlUMsttzb@//9oUx3jWAA)

Takes input in the form `[a, b]` and outputs as `[interior, boundary]`.

#### Explanation

```
                           # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
hMlBPx1Sm.acVdQ*Fm}_ddQ    # implicitly add ddQ
                 m    Q    # map lambda d over Q
                  }_dd     #   inclusive_range(-d, d)
               *F          # cartesian product of the two ranges
        m                  # map over lambda d
           cVdQ            #   vectorized divide d by Q
         .a                #   vector size
       S                   # sort
     x1                    # get list of indices where 1 appears
    P                      # remove the last element
  lB                       # bifurcate over length
hM                         # map to head, this will get the first element for the list and add one for the integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <del>133</del> 121 bytes

*-12 thanks to @Neil*

```
i,x,y,l,B;e(a,b){i=B=0;for(x=-a;x<=a;x++)for(y=-b;y<=b;y++)l=a*a*b*b-x*x*b*b-y*y*a*a,l?i+=l>0:B++;printf("%d %d\n",i,B);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrLCsIwFET3foUIhTxuIK0U1DQK@Q43SV8EYpUqmFD668ZYqJs5w5mpWV/XMVrwEMCBEi3SYPBkpZJcdPcRecm08JVMQSn@mSCZEaGSKZJxUhNNDDHME78wkJCMBnexVLozPylKxWO0w6tDu6zZZs112IEFhcUcb9oOCE@bFpWwx2JhXi7lACvzhcd1yP@XgkPBU5vjp@6c7p@Rvb8)

Comment: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYrLCsIwFET3foUIhTxuIK0U1DQK@Q43SV8EYpUqmFD668ZYqJs5w5mpWV/XMVrwEMCBEi3SYPBkpZJcdPcRecm08JVMQSn@mSCZEaGSKZJxUhNNDDHME78wkJCMBnexVLozPylKxWO0w6tDu6zZZs112IEFhcUcb9oOCE@bFpWwx2JhXi7lACvzhcd1yP@XgkPBU5vjp@6c7p@Rvb8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [117](https://tio.run/##PYrJCsIwFEX3foUIhQyvkFYK6iMK@Q43SScCsUoVTCjtpxtroa7OuUOZtmUZowUPARworIkGQwcrlRTY3Hvi5aTRc55qpL8c5GQwzNkgdVIzzQwzqWd@YWBhbjS4i@XSncVJcY6P3navhuySaptU124HFhTFMd607QgdNjUpYE9xYVYscoCV2cLjOmT/Sy4gF7ONMcZP2TjdPmP6/gI "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AZTECCO place `l?i+=l>0:B++` into for and 0 to [115](https://tio.run/##PYrbCoIwHIfve4oShB3@AzWEaqxgz9HN5onBsrCgDdFHb9nArr7vd6hYV1UhGHDgwYLkDVKg8djeB@TErLijlCmOf9mLWXO/ZM3txVBhz9lJUoqtUEQRTTRzxEV64pdGcSOk2D0G079alKT1Nq2vfQIGJOZTuCnTIzxuGlTCHvPIvIxygJV55HEd8v@lyKDIFptCCJ@qtap7Bvb@Ag)

Comment: Building on @l4m2 [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYpdC4IwGEbv@xUlCPt4B2oI1VjBfkc32/xgsCwsaEP0p7dMsKtzDs9jWGtMjBY8BHAgeY0UaDw09x55MSnuKWWK418HMWke5tbcXSwV7pydJKXYCU00QYoo5onHLJBA5uBWSLF79LZ7NShJq21aXbsELEjMx3hTtkN42NSohD3mC/NykQOszBce1yH/X4oMimy2Mcb4MY1T7TOy9xc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 65 bytes

Prompts for a followed by b and outputs boundary the interior:

```
((1+2×a)++/2×⌊n)-⎕←2×¯1++/0=1|n←⎕×(1-(((⌽⍳a),0,⍳a)*2)÷(a←⎕)*2)*.5
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv4aGobbR4emJmtra@kD6UU9XnqYuUA1QBZB7aL0hUNzA1rAmDygAFD48XcNQV0ND41HP3ke9mxM1dQx0wLSWkebh7RqJEEUgnpae6X@gBVz/07hMuYy5QKShKZCy4IKQhkDSEiJkCJUyMgAiAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, <del>43</del> 41 bytes

Returns the number of interior points on the top of the stack, and the number of boundary points on the bottom.

```
∩/+<1:=1./+ⁿ2÷:-⍉☇1⇡+1×2..⊂
```

[Try It](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4oipLys8MTo9MS4vK-KBvzLDtzot4o2J4piHMeKHoSsxw5cyLi7iioI1IDMK)

```
∩/+<1:=1./+ⁿ2÷:-⍉☇1⇡+1×2..⊂
               -⍉☇1⇡+1×2..⊂ # generates a point array spanning the [-a,a]×[-b,b] rectangle, 
                             # we also leave a copy of a and b to divide the coordinates later
             ÷: # divide each x coordinate by a and each y by b
           ⁿ2 # square each coordinate
         /+ # sum each coordinate pair
        . # create a copy of the sums so we can check two conditions (interior and boundary)
      =1 # boundary check
   <1: # the interior point check
∩/+ # since the checks return boolean masks, sum them to get a point count.
```

Comment: [Try It](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4oipLys8MTo9MS4vK-KBvzLDtzot4o2J4piHMeKHoSsxw5cyLi7iioLCpCA1IDMK)

Comment: Oh, completely missed that feature, I'll edit my submission with your link!

Comment: Also, most of the Uiua code has a section that details how it works. For [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269091/119544)

Comment: Removing the trailing fix (¤), since join doesn't need array args. -2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 94 bytes

```perl
sub{($a,$b,@r)=@_;map{//;$r[1+($b*$b*$'*$'+$a*$a*$_*$_<=>$a*$a*$b*$b)]++for-$b..$b}-$a..$a;@r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLRasIwFIbv@xSHLWytrbp0OmezjrK7XexusAuRkmAdhZlIWhkiPnuXxCQdajjQLzn/@ZvkZFvJn2m3ayr4rJo2yz6ErEiA1nnX7NghRDRBLClklBcl2dDtYTwmSC5wHCI20HGvIkZ0oKNU8ZK/2pnOR8s4Xgs5RGw0Quw4RFR9KSnksSPBZg9Fq34KOYQBqHELFOxgDt55W8laSM1vYsdXVO6NeAHTxGoeHUywI8UAy@RciR2laS/Faa98dqt9CZ4n1zy9El@YnynnF4IJnl319AIPT/PZ1X2mD@4gDnA66ffslREJ1P2H5p6jg1na7G1X0S/lbVlzC0yoJqOSeJHO6MU7tD5VRKdc3Zgc@Hq4@VIEtW1V5jNazNXUkLG4@efBhPPQdPJgtsWZz@jHINTUkPc4BivBq1Ifq@bfpPsD)

Spaceship operator `<=>` comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 40 chars

```
+/¨0(>,=)⊂{+/¯1,2*⍨⍵÷k}¨,(⊂k+1)-⍳1+2×k←⎕
```

How to use and test:

```
      +/¨0(>,=)⊂{+/¯1,2*⍨⍵÷k}¨,(⊂k+1)-⍳1+2×k←⎕
⎕:
      5 3
41 4 

      {+/¨0(>,=)⊂{+/¯1,2*⍨⍵÷k}¨,(⊂k+1)-⍳1+2×k←⍵}¨(5 3)(5 15)(8 5)(8 1)(9 15)(15 15)(20 20)
 41 4  221 12  119 4  15 4  417 4  697 12  1245 12
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 93 Bytes

An immediate window function that takes input \$a\$ from `[A1]` and \$b\$ from `[B1]` of the activesheet object and outputs to the immediate window console.

Assumes a clean console environment. Maybe re-run after executing `u=0:v=0`.

<sup>*Note: This solution has been restricted to 32-Bit versions of Excel VBA as [`^` is the `LongLong` type literal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143645/61846) in 64-Bit versions*</sup>

```vb
For x=[-A1]To[A1]:For y=[-B1]To[B1]:t=x^2/[A1^2]+y^2/[B1^2]:u=u-(t<1):v=v-(t=1):Next y,x:?u,v
```

#### Commented Version

```vb
For x=[-A1]To[A1]            '' iter over x axis
  For y=[-B1]To[B1]          '' iter over y axis
    t=x^2/[A1^2]+y^2/[B1^2]  '' calc lattice point sumsq
    u=u-(t<1)                '' incr. internal point count if needed
    v=v-(t=1)                '' incr. boundary point count if needed
Next y,x                     '' loop
?u,v                         '' print point counts
```